# AbiWord crashed while I was writing a paper

Tags: abiword

I was just writing a four page paper for my class. I have been using AbiWord since I installed Ubuntu on my laptop. I was almost done and ready to submit the paper when my laptop froze up and closed the word file about 30 seconds later. This made me panic like hell as I had worked on the paper for the past 5 hours. I found a backup copy of the file somewhere in my directory, but it looks like HTML code. The file is stored in the format "untitled.abw.saved". Does anybody know how I can restore this file so I have my neat original paper?

Comment: While I'm uncertain this will work, try making a copy of the backup and rename it to `untitled.abw`.

Comment: I tried doing that -it doesn't work. I found an online tool that converts html to text and was able to restore the file that way

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a copy of untitled.abw.saved and save it as untitled.abw.saved.html.
2. Open untitled.abw.saved.html in LibreOffice Writer or in Google Docs, convert it to any other text document format that AbiWord supports, and save the converted document.

Answer (score -1):

> I tried to open the file and it says "error unable to import [file name]".

When AbiWord begins loading the file and then exits with an error. Validate the XML code contents of the file. It is just a text file that you can open with Notepad++, Pluma, Vim, Nano, Emacs text editor.

https://jsonformatter.org/xml-validator JSON XML Validator, was used to find a single error in XML code from AbiWord Editor file Freds_document.abw Use any XML Validator tool you find. I ran the file Freds_document.abw through the JSON XML Validator to verify correct valid XML code. Freds_document.abw.saved could also have been used by copying or moving to a different file name Like: Fred_test1.abw

Abiword had inserted an extra ' props="" ' in front of a " props="Courier xxxxx " Just delete the malformed string props="" from the text file. ReValidate this XML file. The JSON XML Validator showed me that it was in line 62 and character 331. I Would not have found this error that prevented me from loading file into AbiWord editor, with out an XML Validator tool.

Used a copy of the original file to validate and edit. Leave the original file untouched. I used filename Fred_Sample.abw to edit and correct text problems.

[Abiword_recovery wordpress blog](https://stephenmw.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/abiword_recovery)

[How to Open, Edit, Convert .ABW files May 2023](https://www.lifewire.com/abw-file-2619450)